# Can we create a Qt exe without having Qml files in it?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to Qt, all the development we have done so far for our UI project is using qml.
When I release this project to somebody who don't have Qt installed I'm sharing the .qml files as well (when packaging the exe).
Is there a method/process to share a qt exe without sharing the .qml files?

Comment: What do you mean saying QML files - application's qml files of Qt system files?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have your QML files outside of the app and you load them something like this:

```
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("application.qml"));
view.show();
```

if you want to integrate your QML files directly in code and hide them from users you should use Qt Resource System. Add Qt Resource file to your project and pack all your QML files into it. You can then use them in your app like this:

```
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/application.qml"));
view.show();
```

More info about Deploying QML Applications you can read [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html)